# What is difference between two formulae?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int d,  i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, first_sum, second_sum, total;
  
  printf("Enter the first single digit : ");
  scanf("%1d", &d);
  
  printf("Enter the first group of five digits : ");
  scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d",&i1, &i2,&i3, &i4, &i5 );
  
  printf("Enter the second group of five digits : ");
  scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d",&j1, &j2,&j3, &j4, &j5 );

  first_sum = d + i2 + i4 + j1 + j3 + j5;
  second_sum = i1 + i3 + i5 + j2 + j4;
  total = 3 * first_sum + second_sum;

  printf("check digit : %d\n : ", 9 - ((total - 1) % 10)); // 9 - ((total - 1) % 10))
  return 0;
}
```

This is my code and my input is

```
Enter the first single digit : 0
Enter the first group of five digits : 13800
Enter the second group of five digits : 15173
```

If I change the formula

`9 - ((total - 1) % 10)`

into

`10 - (total % 10)`

then I think in some cases it has different results; if the total is 10, I'll get a different result.

But how do I explain it to someone?

I calculated those on my book, and I was Googling but I have no idea.

Comment: The formulas are totally different, and should produce different results. Do you understand how parentheses affect math calculations, and what operator precedence is in C?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your question about the % operator?  9 % 10 gives 1, where 10 % 10 gives 0.  So sometimes the formulas will give the same answer and other times they will be different.

Comment: @KenWhite: The two formulae are not totally different; they share the form `10-r - (total-r) % 10` and produce 90% the same results. Operator precedence is irrelevant as both formula are fully parenthesized, so there is never any choice of operator grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Assume `total > 0`, let us replace `total` with `10x+y` where `y` is a single digit value.

```
         9 - ((total - 1) % 10))  ?==  10 - (total % 10)  Original
         9 - ((10x+y - 1) % 10))  ?==  10 - (10x+y % 10)  Substitute total with 10x+y
    10 - 1 - ((10x+y - 1) % 10))  ?==  10 - (10x+y % 10)  Substitute 9 with 10 - 1
       - 1 - ((10x+y - 1) % 10))  ?==     - (10x+y % 10)  Subtract 10

if y > 0 then
       - 1 - (     y - 1)         ?==     - (y)           Apply %
           -       y              ?==     -  y            -1 - -1 is 0
                   y               ==        y            Success (QED)

if y == 0 then
- 1 - ((10x+y        - 1) % 10))  ?==     - (10x+y % 10)  Copy line #4 above
- 1 - ((10x          - 1) % 10))  ?==     - (10x   % 10)  Let y == 0
- 1 - ((10(x-1) + 10 - 1) % 10))  ?==     - (10x   % 10)  Replace 10x with 10(x-1) + 10  
- 1 - ((10(x-1) +      9) % 10))  ?==     - (10x   % 10)  Replace 10 - 1 with 9
- 1 - ((               9)     ))  ?==     - (0)           Apply %
- 10                               ≠         0            Subtract and fail
```

Formulae not the same for all positive `total`.  Fails when last digit is zero for `total > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For positive `total`, the two formula both produce the remainder of `total` modulo 10 except that, when `total` is a multiple of 10, the former produces 0 and the latter produces 10:

| Remainder of `total` | First Formula | Second Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | 9 |

To see this, let’s write `total` as `10*q+r`, where `r` is the remainder modulo 10, so 0 ≤ `r` < 10. For example, if total is `123`, it equals `10*12 + 3`. First, let’s consider then case where 0 < `r`. Then:

- In `9 - ((total - 1) % 10)`, substituting `10*q+r` for `total` gives `9 - ((10*q+r - 1) % 10)`, which equals `9 - (r-1)` = `10 - r`.
- In `10 - (total % 10)`, substituting `10*q+r` for `total` gives `10 - (10*q + r) % 10`, which equals `10 - r`.

So, for 0 < `r`, the two formula give the same result. Now consider the case where 0 = `r`. Then:

- `9 - ((total - 1) % 10)` equals `9 - (10*q + 0 - 1) % 10`, which equals `9 - 9 % 10`, which is 0.
- `10 - (total % 10)` equals `10 - (10*q + 0) % 10`, which equals `10 - 0 % 10`, which is 10.

Thus, the two formula produce the same value whenever the remainder of total modulo 10 is nonzero, while, when the remainder is zero, the first formula produces 0 and the latter produces 10.

Answer (score -1):

the two formulas are different there are mathematical laws such as bodmass rule to determine which of addition/substraction/multiplication/division will take place first. over the top of that in c language too there are right and left precedence in c language. however, sometimes wen you get the same answer it is just because of coincidence.
if you could state the exact question about what you are supposed to perform in the code than we can help you provide which is an appropriate formula according to your requirement.